# Artifactory - How to push ruby gems?

Tags: rubygems, artifactory

How do you push a ruby gem to an artifactory gem repository?

when I try and do a push, I get this error `Method not allowed`

```
gem push active_cube-0.0.9.gem --host https://gems.example.com/artifactory/api/gems/gems/  -k rubygems --verbose
GET https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
Getting SRV record failed: DNS result has no information for _rubygems._tcp.gems.internal.mx
GET https://gems.example.com/artifactory/api/gems/gems/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
Pushing gem to https://gems.example.com/artifactory/api/gems/gems/...
POST https://gems.example.com/artifactory/api/gems/gems//api/v1/gems
405 Method Not Allowed
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 405,
    "message" : "Method Not Allowed"
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The tailing `/` in host url is reason for 405 Method Not Allowed.
This log line gives a hint that something went wrong with url composing:

```
POST https://gems.example.com/artifactory/api/gems/gems//api/v1/gems
```

See this `gems//api`?..
So the command line should supply host without tailing slash:

```
gem push active_cube-0.0.9.gem --host https://gems.example.com/artifactory/api/gems/gems -k rubygems --verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the reverse proxy that sits in front of artifactory is configured, you may need to change `gems.example.com/artifactory/api/gems/gems/` to `gems.example.com/api/gems/gems/`

The proper procedure is to

1. Pull api key
2. `gem push`

Use curl to get the api_key and save it to `~/.gem/credentials`. (This will override the contents of ~/.gem/credentials, best to back it up first.

```
cp ~/.gem/credentials ~/.gem/credentials.back

curl -L gems.example.com/api/gems/gems/api/v1/api_key.yaml \ 
-u admin:<correct-horse-battery-staple> > ~/.gem/credentials
```

The contents of `~/.gem/credentials` will look like:

```
---
:rubygems_api_key: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

From there, use `gem push`. The `-k rubygems` option corresponds to the line `:rubygems_api_key` in the ~/.gem/credentials file.

```
gem push active_cube-0.0.9.gem --host https://gems.example.com/api/gems/gems/  -k rubygems --verbose
```